# WebAPI .getJSON function and querying a list with linq returning "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, getjson

I am actually trying to understand a bit ASP.NET WEBAPI . I want to query a list of artists which are contained in an ArtistController class.

Here is a screenshot of the front end.

[image: Front end screenshot]

Here is my controller

```
public class ArtistsController : ApiController
{
    Artist[] artists = new Artist[]
    {
        new Artist { Name = "Metallica",Id ="65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab",Country ="US",Aliases ="Metalica" },
        new Artist { Name = "Lady Gaga",Id ="650e7db6-b795-4eb5-a702-5ea2fc46c848",Country ="US",Aliases ="Lady Ga Ga,Stefani Joanne Angelina Germanotta" },
        new Artist { Name = "Mumford & Sons",Id ="c44e9c22-ef82-4a77-9bcd-af6c958446d6",Country ="GB",Aliases ="" },
        new Artist { Name = "Mott the Hoople",Id ="435f1441-0f43-479d-92db-a506449a686b",Country ="GB",Aliases ="Mott The Hoppie,Mott The Hopple" },
        new Artist { Name = "Megadeth",Id ="a9044915-8be3-4c7e-b11f-9e2d2ea0a91e",Country ="US",Aliases ="Megadeath" },
        new Artist { Name = "John Coltrane",Id ="b625448e-bf4a-41c3-a421-72ad46cdb831",Country ="US",Aliases ="John Coltraine,John William Coltrane" }
    }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Artist> GetAllArtists()
    {
        return artists;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetArtist(string name)
    {
        //IEnumerable<Artist> ArtistQuery = (from Artist in artists
        //                                  where Artist.Name.Contains(name)
        //                                  select Artist).ToList();
        IEnumerable<Artist> ArtistQuery = from Artist in artists
                                          where Artist.Name.Contains(name)
                                          select Artist;
        if (ArtistQuery == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(ArtistQuery);
    }
}
```

I have an `IHttpActionResult` where I have created a linq query.

On the front end, I have a jQuery `.getJSON` method which I would like to get an artist by name. I think that the issue lies here, I am returning a list of artists but I am specifying a "name" only.

```
function find()
{
    var id = $('#artistid').toString();
    $.getJSON(uri + '/' + name)
    .done(function (data) 
    {
        $('#artist').text(formatItem(data));
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,err)
    {
        $('#artist').text('Error : ' + err);
    });

}

function formatItem(item) { return item.Name + ' ' + item.Country; }
```

Here is the we api configuration

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) { 
    // Web API configuration and services // Web API routes 
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); 
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            name: "DefaultApi", 
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
    ); 
}
```

I am getting an error "Undefined" "Undefined".

There are no compilation errors on the back end.

There are no javascript errors in the Chrome console as well.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: What does `formatItem(data)` do?

Comment: There is the function                                                                                           function formatItem(item)
    {
        return item.Name + ' ' + item.Country;
    }                                                                                                                It displays the output as "Artist name" "Country"

Comment: If you call the API endpoint with Fiddler of with Postman, do you get back valid results from your API?

Comment: The jquery.getJson which works and sends all the artists is as follows                     </script>
    <script>
    var uri = 'api/artists';

    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Send an AJAX request
      $.getJSON(uri)
          .done(function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of artists.
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
              // Add a list item for the product.
              $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#artists'));
            });
          });
    });

Comment: When I do http://localhost:53020/api/artists/ in postman, I correctly get the list of artists in JSON format.   [
  {
    "Name": "Metallica",
    "Id": "65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab",
    "Country": "US",
    "Aliases": "Metalica"
  }, ........]

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript for `formatItem` is expecting one item `Artist`.

```
 function formatItem(item) { return item.Name + ' ' + item.Country; }
```

But your `GetArtist` is returning an `IEnumerable<Artist>` which would explain why you see `undefined  undefined`.

Either you return only one `Artist`from your `GetArtist`

```
public IHttpActionResult GetArtist(string name) {       
    IEnumerable<Artist> ArtistQuery = from Artist in artists
                                      where Artist.Name.Contains(name)
                                      select Artist;
    if (ArtistQuery.Count() == 0) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(ArtistQuery.First());
}
```

Or let your javascript handle multiple results from the service

```
function find() {
    $.getJSON(uri + '/' + name) //This should resolve to you web api endpoint `api/artists/getartist/{name}`
    .done(function (data) {
        if(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, item)) { 
                // Add a list item for the found artists to artist. 
                $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#artist'));
            }
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,err)
    {
        $('#artist').text('Error : ' + err);
    });

}
```

**UPDATE**

The reason it is not hitting the `GetArtist` is because the uri you submit does not confirm to the convention of your configuration.

For simplicity, change your parameter name from `name` to `id`. That will let the action conform to he mapped convention.

**UPDATE 2: ATTRIBUTE ROUTING**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/artists")]
public class ArtistsController : ApiController
{
    Artist[] artists = new Artist[]
    {
        new Artist { Name = "Metallica",Id ="65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab",Country ="US",Aliases ="Metalica" },
        new Artist { Name = "Lady Gaga",Id ="650e7db6-b795-4eb5-a702-5ea2fc46c848",Country ="US",Aliases ="Lady Ga Ga,Stefani Joanne Angelina Germanotta" },
        new Artist { Name = "Mumford & Sons",Id ="c44e9c22-ef82-4a77-9bcd-af6c958446d6",Country ="GB",Aliases ="" },
        new Artist { Name = "Mott the Hoople",Id ="435f1441-0f43-479d-92db-a506449a686b",Country ="GB",Aliases ="Mott The Hoppie,Mott The Hopple" },
        new Artist { Name = "Megadeth",Id ="a9044915-8be3-4c7e-b11f-9e2d2ea0a91e",Country ="US",Aliases ="Megadeath" },
        new Artist { Name = "John Coltrane",Id ="b625448e-bf4a-41c3-a421-72ad46cdb831",Country ="US",Aliases ="John Coltraine,John William Coltrane" }
    }
    };
    // GET api/artists
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Artist> GetAllArtists()
    {
        return artists;
    }

    // GET api/artists/John
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{name}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetArtist(string name)
    {        
        IEnumerable<Artist> ArtistQuery = from Artist in artists
                                          where Artist.Name.Contains(name)
                                          select Artist;
        if (ArtistQuery == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(ArtistQuery);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this from ur code, "   var artist = data[0]  "; it will only return the first item in the list "Metallica US". How can I get all the artists which matches the name ? using regex ??

Comment: Now it is displaying all the names :)    There's a ")" missing in order for it to work. Here it is.                                                                 .done(function (data) 
        {
            if(data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) { 
                    // Add a list item for the found artists to artist. 
                    $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#artist'));
                }
                    )}
        })

Comment: If it's displaying all then that means it's hitting the `GetAllArtists`. How are you configuring your routes. Update your question to Show the route config for the api

Comment: public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: You need to add that kind of information to your original post. You can edit it. I'll add it now.

Comment: I changed it to id but it does not make a difference.  public IHttpActionResult GetArtist(string id)
        {
            IEnumerable<Artist> ArtistQuery = from Artist in artists
                                              where Artist.Name.Contains(id)
                                              select Artist;
       

            if (ArtistQuery == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(ArtistQuery);
        }

Comment: What is the uri you are sending to the controller. ie (uri + '/' + name)

Comment: Yes.     $.getJSON(uri + '/' + name)

Comment: That is the url to the page and not to your controller. I think you may need to go read up on some of the tutorials on using api,net web api with javascript.

Comment: alright. I'll update the controller to use attribute routing.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, appreciate your help but this does not solve the issue. I believe that the problem is with the JSON because my linq returns the correct list which contains "John" when I test it in a console application.